# Querying against an inner field in postgresql jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-12

I have a jsonb column, which has a structure like this:

```
{
    .....other fields,
    "a" : {
        "b" : {
            "c" : "some value",
            ....other fields
        }
        .....other fields
    },
    ...other fields
}
```

I can have query like this, properties being column name in table MyTable:

```
SELECT * from
  MyTable t
WHERE t.properties @> '{"a":{"b":{"c": "some value"}}}';
```

But it is possible that fields before "c" are different,ie we can have:

```
{
        .....other fields,
        "m" : {
            "n" : {
                "c" : "some value",
                ....other fields
            }
            .....other fields
        },
        ...other fields
    }
```

How to modify my query for such a scenario?

Comment: Which Postgres Version are you using?

Comment: I a having version 12.

Comment: Then you can use a `jsonpath` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the nesting is always at the same level you can use a JSON/Path expression:

```
select *
from the_table
where properties @@ '$.*.*.c == "some value"'
```